# Prevent process seeing existing instance

Tags: c#, mutex, sandbox

Here's the situation.

I have an application which for all intents and purposes I have to treat like a black box.

I need to be able to open multiple instances of this application each with a set of files. The syntax for opening this is `executable.exe file1.ext file2.ext`.

If I run `executable.exe` x amount of times with no arguments, new instances open fine.

If I run `executable.exe file1.ext` followed by `executable.exe file2.ext` then the second call opens file 2 in the existing window rather than creating a new instance. **This interferes with the rest of my solution and is the problem.**

My solution wraps this application and performs various management operations on it, here's one of my wrapper classes:

```
public class myWrapper
{
    public event EventHandler<IntPtr> SplashFinished;
    public event EventHandler ProcessExited;
    private const string aaTrendLocation = @"redacted";
    //private const string aaTrendLocation = "notepad";
    private readonly Process _process;
    private readonly Logger _logger;

    public myWrapper(string[] args, Logger logger =null)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger?.WriteLine("Intiialising new wrapper object...");
        if (args == null || args.Length < 1) args = new[] {""};
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(aaTrendLocation,args.Aggregate((s,c)=>$"{s} {c}"));
        _process = new Process{StartInfo = info};

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Starting process...");
        _logger?.WriteLine($"Process: {_process.StartInfo.FileName} || Args: {_process.StartInfo.Arguments}");
        _process.Start();
        Task.Run(()=>MonitorSplash());
        Task.Run(() => MonitorLifeTime());
    }

    private void MonitorLifeTime()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Monitoring lifetime...");
        while (!_process.HasExited)
        {
            _process.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
        _logger?.WriteLine("Process exited!");
        _logger?.WriteLine("Invoking!");
        ProcessExited?.BeginInvoke(this, null, null, null);
    }

    private void MonitorSplash()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Monitoring Splash...");
        while (!_process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Trend"))
        {
            _process.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        _logger?.WriteLine("Splash finished!");
        _logger?.WriteLine("Invoking...");
        SplashFinished?.BeginInvoke(this,_process.MainWindowHandle,null,null);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Killing trend...");
        _process.Kill();
    }

    public IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Fetching handle...");
        _process.Refresh();
        return _process.MainWindowHandle;
    }

    public string GetMainTitle()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Fetching Title...");
        _process.Refresh();
        return _process.MainWindowTitle;
    }
}
```

My wrapper class all works fine until I start providing file arguments and this unexpected instancing behaviour kicks in.

I can't modify the target application and nor do I have access to its source to determine whether this instancing is managed with Mutexes or through some other feature. Consequently, I need to determine if there is a way to prevent the new instance seeing the existing one. Would anyone have any suggestions?

---

**TLDR: How do I prevent an application that is limited to a single instance determining that there is already an instance running**

---

To clarify (following suspicious comments), my company's R&D team wrote `executable.exe` but I don't have time to wait for their help in this matter (I have days not months) and have permission to do whatever required to deliver the required functionality (there's a lot more to my solution than this question mentions) swiftly.

---

With some decompiling work I can see that the following is being used to find the existing instance.

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
```

Is there any way to mess with this short of creating multiple copies of the application with different names? I looked into renaming the `Process` on the fly but apparently this isn't possible short of writing kernel exploits...

Comment: Looks like that application is well designed and functions really well. Does the application open the files in read-only mode?

Comment: The sarcasm is palpable, just for the record, I didn't write the target. It does not but the files that I need opening in the different instances will be different anyway. So I'd essentially call `exe file1 file2` `exe file3 file4` and want 2 instances with the relevant files in.

Comment: However the jury is out on exactly the meaning of the words `If I run executable.exe file.ext followed by executable.exe file.ext again then the second call opens the file in the existing window rather than creating a new instance` i mean i run heaps of command line stuff in parallel, i have never seen this

Comment: I mean that if I don't provide a file argument, I can open as many instances as I want but if I provide file arguments, after the first run it opens the files in the first instance. Horribly inconsistent behaviour that's really messed me up.

Comment: Create copy of the file provided as arguments before executing the process?

Comment: @ilansch that doesn't matter, I'm trying to send different files to different instances

Comment: Thats not the sample you put in your question. You used the same file name. Anyway, it seem like you try to hack that program and i dont think this is allowed in SO. If what you do is leggit, contact whoever created that program.

Comment: @ilansch I know, I've edited the question. I'm pretty sure it's not against SO policy to hack my way around badly written code from within my own company with permission to implement functionality that our sales team has sold to a company rather than wait 6-12 months for R&D to fix it and issue an update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Dave Lucre's answer I solved it by creating new instances of the executable bound to my wrapper class. Initially, I inherited `IDisposable` and removed the temporary files in the Disposer but for some reason that was causing issues where the cleanup would block the application, so now my main program performs cleanup at the end.

---

My constructor now looks like:

```
public AaTrend(string[] args, ILogger logger = null)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _logger?.WriteLine("Initialising new aaTrend object...");
    if (args == null || args.Length < 1) args = new[] { "" };
    _tempFilePath = GenerateTempFileName();
    CreateTempCopy(); //Needed to bypass lazy single instance checks
    HideTempFile(); //Stops users worrying
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(_tempFilePath, args.Aggregate((s, c) => $"{s} {c}"));
    _process = new Process { StartInfo = info };
}
```

With the two new methods:

```
    private void CreateTempCopy()
    {
        _logger?.WriteLine("Creating temporary file...");
        _logger?.WriteLine(_tempFilePath);
        File.Copy(AaTrendLocation, _tempFilePath);
    }

    private string GenerateTempFileName(int increment = 0)
    {
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(AaTrendLocation); //Obtain pass components.
        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AaTrendLocation);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(AaTrendLocation);
        string tempName = $"{directory}\\{fileNameWithoutExtension}-{increment}{extension}"; //Re-assemble path with increment inserted.
        return File.Exists(tempName) ? GenerateTempFileName(++increment) : tempName; //If this name is already used, increment an recurse otherwise return new path.
    }
```

Then in my main program:

```
    private static void DeleteTempFiles()
    {
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(AaTrend.AaTrendLocation);
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "aaTrend-*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
```

---

As a side-note, this approach will only work for applications with (lazy) methods of determining instancing that rely on `Process.GetProcessByName()`; it won't work if a `Mutex` is used or if the executable name is explicitly set in the manifests.

Comment: Glad you got this sorted.  aaTrend... That's System Platform right?

Comment: @DaveLucre if that's what they've rebranded wonderware to now... Seems like they change the branding every few years

Comment: yep Wonderware is  called Aveva System Platform now.  But it's all the same stuff.

Comment: Ahh, I bailed out of Schneider last year so wouldn't know...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem in the past by creating copies of the source executable.  In your case, you could:

- Save the 'original.exe' in a specific location.
- Each time you need to call it, create a copy of original.exe and name it 'instance_xxxx.exe', where xxxx is a unique number.
- Execute your new instance exe as required, and when it completes you can delete it
- You could possibly even re-use the instances by creating a pool of them

Comment: Aye that's what I was thinking once I found out how it was doing the checks. It's a little messy though so I'm going to try and see if there's a more elegant solution in the meantime.